# quartz job to wait till start and standby after completion

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, quartz

I'm using quartz job my requirement is like I get some data to be persist in DB but before that I need to perform some modification on given data so I started processing the data in background using quartz. But now what is happening some of the time job is getting standby even before starting and due to that some of the data payload didn't get processed.
How can I maintain the job to be wait until the job complete its work.

```
 scheduler.start();
    scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    scheduler.standby();
```

In my code if job starts before 3 second the standby will wait for job to complete the task but some of the time job taking more time to stat.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making your job wait for data, you can

1. Start your job every x minutes
2. Don't spawn new jobs if there's already a working one so they
   won't overlap

Comment: Actually whenever i receive data I start the job and pass that data to job context for processing if I do something like that wont meet my requirement.

Comment: Ok then why don't you wait for data processing to finish before you start the job? are they separate threads?